# uisng to_date function still get date format picture ends before converting entire input string error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code where I want to see if a date is less than a year ago:

```
select id 
from mytable 
where id= :p_id 
and (to_date(trunc(sysdate), 'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_date(datewhen, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) < 365;
```

I keep getting the error:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

Looking at other question with the same error on StackOverflow I see the solution usually is to use the to_date function which I am doing so I am unsure why this is occuring. The `datewhen` field is of type `Date`.

Comment: You don&amp;#39;t need to use the to_date function in "to_date(trunc(sysdate), 'yyyy-mm-dd')" because   you have alread used the trunc().

Comment: Using `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date` makes no sense whatsoever. Do **NOT** do that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `to_date()` with the columnes of DATE data type. `to_date()` converts character string to a value of DATE data type. It makes no sense to convert the DATE to DATE. In a first step `datewhen` column of type DATE will be implicitly converted into a character data type by using the default date format (that's most probably not `'yyyy-mm-dd'`) and this is the culprit of the `ORA-01830` error.

So your statement should look something like this:

```
select id from mytable where id = :p_id and (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(datewhen)) < 365;
```

I'd calculate the difference in the months or years instead of days:

```
... where months_between(sysdate, datewhen) < 12
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `datewhen` column is char/varchar formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` then you have to do the `to_date` conversion on `datewhen`, but not on `SYSDATE`: it's already a date and doesn't need to be converted.

To filter on a date within the past 365 days, compare it to `SYSDATE - 365`:

```
select id
from mytable
where id = :p_id
  and to_date(datewhen, 'yyyy-mm-dd') > sysdate - 365;
```

But a year isn't always 365 days: on leap years it's 366 days. To get a *one year ago* value that's always correct, subtract an interval of one year from the current date:

```
select id
from mytable
where id = :p_id
  and datewhen > sysdate - interval '1' year;
```

One more thing: the Oracle `DATE` type isn't just a date; it's a date and a time. `SYSDATE` returns the current date *and* time. Try this query:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Unless you run this at exactly midnight you'll see a time component as well.

Say your query runs on 2 September 2017 at 10 AM and you're looking for a date within the past year. You'd expect to get the date 3 September 2016, but you wouldn't because at 10 AM `SYSDATE` is 3 September 2016 at 10:00:00. That's greater than the plain date 3 September 2016, which is 3 September 2016 at 0:00:00, so records with a `datewhen` of `2016-09-03' won't be included.

To ignore the time component of an Oracle `DATE` value, use `TRUNC`. Your final query should look something like this:

```
select id
from mytable
where id = :p_id
  and datewhen > trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' year;
```

Comment: You could also use `add_month{SYSDATE,-12)`

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, good catch! I'd forgotten about `add_months`.

Answer (score 0):

you use TO_DATE function when the value in character format

Syntax

The syntax for the TO_DATE function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
 TO_DATE( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] )
```